# Keycloak custom brute force detection

Tags: authentication, keycloak, brute-force

I am trying to figure out it is possible to create custom brute force detection in Keycloak? Logic that they have doesn't match requirements so I have to extend or create my own provider.
For example what I need is after X failed login attempts, user should be blocked X minutes. After user get unlocked and again failed I want to specify Y time. In Keycloak currently it going to be the same X value for that user because they have some algorithm to calculate wait time:
wait time * (countOfFailures / maxFailures) The division is an integer division rounded down to a whole number

and if i set 10 min max first 5 fails will be 10min fail, then on six one will be 20min.

Answer (score 1):

I have experimentalized by Quarkus Keycloak 21.0.2 in this theme.

We customized LoginFormsSpi's Freemarker provider.

keycloak.conf->

```
spi-#SPI_NAME#-provider=#PROVIDER_NAME#
```

By BruteForceProtector it doesn't works!
I found that keycloak can't decide which implemetation should use.

Keycloak decide it in ***DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.checkProvider***

1. with ***keycloak.#SPI_NAME#.provider*** system property you can choose default implementation
2. Just one implementation is exists
3. By ProviderFactory's order() method's priorization
4. A there was some magic if provider contains 'default'

The first solution work's.

The 3.-d solution work's.

**If your provider's order method return >0 than your provider wins**

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak has an SPI named `org.keycloak.services.managers.BruteForceProtectorSpi` that you can implement but it's in the `server-spi-private` module which means it supposed to be used only by the Keycloak itself and not for being extended. I have never tried to implement an SPI of that module. It may not work at all or even if you manage to make it work, the interface and the way it's used may change in future versions without any notice.

**EDIT:**

Remember if you're overwriting such a service provider (that Keycloak expect to have only one instance of it active at a time), you should define it in the WildFly configuration under keycloak subsystem (I don't know how to do it in the recent Quarkus versions, but you get the idea) and then set it as default provider. Here is what I did when I wanted to add a custom `LocaleSelector` provider:

```xml
<spi name="localeSelector">
    <default-provider>custom-locale-selector</default-provider>
    <provider name="customer-locale-selector" enabled="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="prop1" value="value1"/>
        </properties>
    </provider>
</spi>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already try to create that, but the problem is it's not visible on UI and can't turn it ON/OFF, can't change configuration what is the main idea is to be configurable. Will see a bit more, if I figure something I will share solution.

Comment: What exactly do you need to be configured via UI?

Comment: Now when I go to the Server Info/ Providers I can see two brute force protectors, default and mine custom. And when I go to the Realm settings and turn brute force detection it's look like both are running or idk. And when I fail login, I got some exception when authentication flow try to get brute force detector. 
So in short, how to disable default one and just use custom?

Comment: I'm not sure about the recent Quarkus based versions, but for the WildFly based versions, you can define those providers in WildFly configuration and then specify which on should be considered as default. I updated my question to include a sample config as it was not easy to type it in this tiny comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I just created these classes:

- CustomBruteForceProtector
- CustomBruteForceProtectorFactory
- CustomBruteForceProtectorSpi

Then specify them in:
META-INF/services

- org.keycloak.provider.Spi
- org.keycloak.services.managers.BruteForceProtectorFactory

And on the end we need to specify default Protector SPI: (standalone-ha.xml)

```
<spi name="bruteForceProtector">
<default-provider>custom-brute-force-detector</default-provider>
<provider name="custom-brute-force-detector" enabled="true"></provider>
</spi>
```

Then under the Server Info / Providers you are be able to see just your brute force protector:
[image]